# Connect to TFS web portal on a VM

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, web-server, vmware-workstation, team-foundation-server

Disclaimer: Major newbie here.

I'm working on a project where Windows machines connect to our TFS web portal using a VPN. Each machine hosts an Ubuntu Virtual Machine, which is bridged to their respective host. When I'm using Ubuntu, if I try to connect to the web portal, it reports that the address was not found. The main goal is that each VM has the ability to connect to our TFS portal, not using another VPN connection. A friend told me I should find a way of configuring another link between the VM and the VPN, probably through Windows. Is this an easy thing to do? Sorry if I'm mixing subjects.

EDIT: I can access the web portal if I switch the network configuration to NAT, but since I need a static IP to communicate with the host machine through a monitoring software, I can't just start using NAT over Bridged. Is there a way I can add a NAT network, paired with the Bridged one, so that I can reach both my host and the vpn networks?

Comment: If TFS is only reachable through the VPN then the VM has to connect to it through the VPN. You might see if you can bridge the VM to the host VPN connection rather than the host physical network adapter.

Comment: thanks @joeqwerty, the VM is monitoring the host via Nagios, so I must stay connected to the host machine. That's why I'm using a bridged connection. If I bridge the VM to the VPN, does that mean I will lose direct connection to my host machine?

Comment: Fixed the issue by using the following tutorial: http://derpturkey.com/vmware-guest-using-the-host-vpn-client/ .

I provided a static address to my bridged network and created a NAT network. Then I allowed routing through the VPN network.